# Providing Arguments for PGSQL Functions in Go

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I am attempting to pass arguments to the following function in Golang with db.QueryRow(), however it doesn't seem to accept the usual ?.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS upsertplatform(pToken varchar);
CREATE FUNCTION upsertplatform(pToken varchar) RETURNS int as $$
    DECLARE
        _id int = NULL;
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            UPDATE public.platform SET platformToken = pToken WHERE userID = 3 AND platformID = 2 RETURNING id into _id;
            IF NOT FOUND THEN
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO public.platform (userID, platformID, platformToken) VALUES (3, 2, '1234-123-bbasd') RETURNING id into _id;
                EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
                        UPDATE public.platform SET platformToken = '1234-123-bbasd' WHERE userID = 3 AND platformID = 2 RETURNING id into strict _id;
                END;
            END IF;
        EXIT WHEN _id IS NOT NULL;
        END LOOP;
    RETURN 1;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

This is the query I am having issues with, I'm unsure how to pass arguments to it:

```
res := db.QueryRow(`SELECT * FROM upsertplatform( ? )`, "test123")
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Postgres uses $1/$2/etc, not ?.

Comment: You're right, very silly of me to start using ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Postgres drivers use positional notation for parameters, $1, $2,... So just `SELECT * FROM upsertplatform($1)`.